# .ready() triggered after window.beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom-events

We have a few places where we include inline `<script>` blocks which run code, wrapped by `$(document).ready()`. Several of these blocks use methods dependent on other external scripts. During normal page execution this technique works fine, but when the user navigates away from the page before it's completely loaded, the `$(document).ready()` event is triggered and IE is throwing these errors:

> "Object does not support this property or method"

Through some testing I've found out that the `window.beforeunload` event is triggered before any of the `ready` events, so I'd like to be able to prevent the `ready` events from being triggered at that point. Ideally I'd like to have a solution that generalizes so I don't have to modify all of the inline code.

If that's not possible would you suggest wrapping all of the inline code in `try-catch` blocks, determining if all the external scripts have been loaded before executing the inline code, etc?

Comment: Are you loading your jquery plugins __after__ jquery and __before__ your `document.ready` calls?

Comment: so you're inserting a script file within the `onbeforeunload` handler?

Comment: Is upgrading to jQuery 1.4.3 in a few days an option? It adds the ability to delay the `ready` handlers.

Comment: @david - Loading the jQuery library at the top of the page, the other external scripts at the bottom, and the inline scripts are peppered throughout

Comment: @jAndy - Not doing anything within the onbeforeunload handler at the moment, just seems like a convenient place to address the issue

Comment: @nick - Unfortunately it's not for this project, but that sounds like a great feature. I'll definitely consider that for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going with the following solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  $.readyList = null;
 }
</script>
```

It's a little hackier than I would have preferred, but it gets the job done.

Comment: useful hack. +1 for future use ;)

Answer (score 1):

The inline scripts should not be peppered throughout like that if the plugins are loaded after the fact.

A better way, IMO, is to set up your pages like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.customerPlugins.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
               // all inline would go here!
            });
        </script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But if that isn't an option you could (but probably shouldn't) (untested code below):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            var readyQueue = [];
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            readyQueue.push(function(){
               $("body").append("<div />").customPlugin();
            });
        </script>
        <div id="content">
            <script>
                readyQueue.push(function(){
                   $("#content").customPlugin();
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery.customPlugins.js"></script>
        <script>
            // do something like this...
            $(function(){
               var fn;
               while(fn = readyQueue.shift()){
                   fn();
               }
               // if you want to continue to use readyQueue in code 
               // below/after this you could do something like the following:
               readyQueue = {"push": function(fn){
                   fn();
               })};
               // this would execute immediately:
               readyQueue.push(function(){
                   alert('Hello');
               });
            });
        </script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

While you're at it, check out [html5boilerplate.com](http://www.html5boilerplate.com).

Comment: Definitely agree that it would be better to consolidate the inline JS. Unfortunately that's a bigger project than I have time for at the moment.

Comment: Try the second option. It is more proof-of-concept than actual code (its not tested). The [].push to push function trick is very similar to the methods most async scripts out there (google analytics is similar).